# How to handle dynamically-added DOM elements for progressive enhancement without knowing the method of adding?

Tags: javascript, jquery, progressive-enhancement

I have a simple script that that "progressively enhances" specific `<input>` elements with a draggable slider ([demo of the jQuery plugin](http://loopj.com/jquery-simple-slider/demo.html)).

Additional `<input>` elements may be added, and the whole thing will be placed in many different scenarios (it's a pluggable frontend widget). In other words, I cannot hook onto some "Add Another Slider" button's click event, because I have no idea where those additional elements may come from (it may be a button, several buttons, some AJAX call, etc).

To handle those additional elements, currently I'm using:

```
// for any dynamically added elements:
setInterval(find_and_init_all_sliders_that_are_not_yet_inited, 200);
```

Is there a better way?

---

**TL;DR:**

I wanna run a function each time new DOM elements are added. But I have no info or control on how or where those new elements will be added.

Comment: Event delegation is all you need.  Without knowing what you want to do with the added elements it's difficult to really say much more.

Comment: Why don't you know when these elements are added to the page? Don't you have control over your own page?

Comment: @Bergi No I don't, because it will not be used on my page. The idea is to make a plugin ("drop-in"?) that will enhance certain `<input>` elements. It will be used in many different scenarios on different sites. Similar to building a polyfill for, say, `<input type="range">` (the actual task is more specific, but the problem is the same I guess).

Comment: The easier solution will be to let those people who have the control, and who do add the elements, explicitly call your plugin on chosen elements.